# Retrieve 'score' for Swarm check-in via Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to find the largest check-in (by number of coins/points earned) I've had on Foursquare/Swarm.

The [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) has a `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/checkins` endpoint to return a user's check-ins as an array of `check-in` objects. The docs say this object should sometimes contain `total` and `score` properties but I haven't been able to find a check-in with these properties.

Have the `score` and `total` properties been removed? Or does it require querying a specific check-in with the `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/CHECKIN_ID` endpoint?

If a member of the Foursquare team is listening, can we get `total` and `score` added to the `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/checkins` response?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `score` and `total` are only available in the complete checkin object through `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/CHECKIN_ID`

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin